# kernel pca parameters usage : kernel and fit_inverse_transform

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, kernel-density

I am trying to apply Kernel PCA on a mixed dataset (both categorical and numeric). I want to optimize my model but even if I read the documentation, I did not understand the main purpose of fit_inverse_transform and the parameter X_transform_fit_ with dual_coef_. Is there anyone who can explain their purpose and how to interpret them ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the goal of any transformer in scikit-learn (including kernelPCA) is to change dimension of your features. So if we assume your original features have a dimension **d**, the transformer can transform them to a dimension **k**, where **k** <= **d**. 
After fitting the model, you can use the following 2 methods:

1. transform --- Given original features, transform to new features (**d** -> **k**)
2. inverse_transform --- Given new features, transform to original features (**k** -> **d**)

In the case of kernelPCA you need to specifically enable the 2nd option through the parameter `fit_inverse_transform` since by default it is set to `False`. The reason for this is that the inverse_transform method requires some additional computations to be performed (stored in `dual_coef_`).

Check the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py#L287) if still in doubt.

Comment: can this parameter and attributes be used to track the effect of the original features on the principal components? For example how much a feature has an effect the principal component and in which direction